# Android/adb redirect console app output

Tags: android, adb, android-2.2-froyo

I am trying to get the output of a WLAN driver control interface via `adb shell` on a motorola droid 2.  The command is called wlan_cu.  To run the command,I am using:

```
% wlan_cu -itiwlan0 -s /data/jay/stat.sh
```

> Connection established with supplicant .../Connection> Bssid_list,
>   Connect, Disassociate, Status, Full_bssid_list, wPs/
>
> Status   : DISCONNECT 
>  MAC      : f8.7b.7a.7b.b7.9b 
>  SSID : `<empty>` 
>   
>  BSSID    : 00.00.00.00.00.00 
>  
>   Channel  : `<empty>`
>
> Driver/, Connection/, Management/, Show/, Privacy/, scAn/, roaminG/, qOs/, poWer/, eVents/, Bt coexsistance/, Report/, dEbug/, biT/, aboUt, Quit
>   [1]   Segmentation fault      wlan_cu -itiwlan0 -s /data/jay/stat.sh

The `-s` option is to read wlan_cu commands from a script.

> % cat /data/jay/stat.sh 
>  
>   c s 
>    / 
>  
>   q

If I try to redirect the output i.e.

`% wlan_cu -itiwlan0 -s /data/jay/stat.sh &> out.txt`

`out.txt` is created, but empty and the output still goes to screen.  Anyone have an idea? been stuck on this for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to redirect both stdout and stderr to the out.txt. Try this,

```
# wlan_cu -itiwlan0 -s /data/jay/stat.sh > out.txt 2>&1
```